# External audio is not working perfectly after suspend

Tags: sound, suspend, alsa, realtek, audio-jack

### *English*

Headset jack works fine after each booting or after hot plunging. But after resuming from suspend, audio does not work as it should be, when the jack remains connected during suspend. Headsets sound rough, volume becomes low and stereo does not work also.

Sound card is `Realtek ALC3235` in Dell Latitude E7470 running Ubuntu 18.04.2.

### *বাংলা*

প্রতিবার বুট করার পরে বা হেডফোন জ্যাক হটপ্লাগ করার পরে ঠিকঠাক কাজ করে। কিন্তু হেডফোন জ্যাক লাগানো অবস্থাতে সাসপেন্ড করলে, তারপরে সাসপেন্ড থেকে পুনরায় চালু করলে হেডসেট আর ঠিকঠাক কাজ করে না। খানিকটা ঘ্যারঘ্যারে শব্দ শোনা যায়, কম ভল্যুমে, স্টেরিও ব্যবস্থাও কাজ করে না।

`Realtek ALC3235`  সাউন্ডকার্ড সংযুক্ত ডেল ল্যাটিচুড E7470 — এ বর্তমানে উবুন্তু ১৮.০৪.২ চলছে।

Answer (score 0):

## *English*

At length I am able to solve the problem. At first try to load current driver setup, and check if it works.

```
alsactl restore
```

If loading current driver setup does not work, then reinstall the ALSA packages.

Remove the ALSA packages.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
```

Reinstall the same packages.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
```

Check if works, you can try loading current driver setup another time.

```
alsactl restore
```

Hope it will be solve your problem, as like me.

## *বাংলা*

অবশেষে সমস্যার সমাধান হলো।  প্রথমেই চলতি ড্রাইভার সেটাপ লোড করে দেখুন কাজ হয় কিনা।

```
alsactl restore
```

চলতি ড্রাইভার সেটাপ লোড করেও কাজ না হলে আলসা (ALSA) প্যাকেজগুলো আপনার সিস্টেমে পুনঃসংস্থাপন করুন।

প্রথমে আলসা প্যাকেজগুলো অপসারণ করুন।

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
```

সিস্টেমে সেগুলো পুনরায় সংস্থাপন করুন।

```
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
```

এতে কাজ হবে, না হলে চলতি ড্রাইভার সেটাপ আরেকবার লোড করে দেখতে পরেন।

```
alsactl restore
```

আশা করি আমার মতো আপনার সমস্যা সমাধান হয়ে গেছে।